# Evaluation of K-means clustering ( accuracy)

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I created a 2-dimensional random datasets (composed from a dataset of points and a column of labels) for centroid based k-means clustering in MATLAB where each point is represented by a vector of X and Y (the point coordinates) and each label represents the data point cluster,see example in figure below.

[image: figure1]

I applied the K-means clustering algorithm on these point datasets. I need help with the following:
What function can I use to evaluate the accuracy of the K-means algorithm? In more detail: My aim is to score the Kmeans algorithm based on how many assigned labels it correctly identifies by comparing with assigned numbers by matlab. For example, I verify if the point (7.200592168, 11.73878455) is assigned with the point (6.951107307, 11.27498898) to the same cluster... etc.

Comment: Are you looking for [`sumd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#buefs04-sumd)?

Comment: @beaker No. I am looking of a method or a function that can help computing the accuracy of the clustering algorithm in this case. In this case, the k-means algorithm is in python, and I use the 2 dimenional dataset generated by matlab as input. The result of the algorithm is the clusters needed and I want to verify the accuracy of the algorithm based on the label that matlab generates with the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you are looking for the [adjusted rand index](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score.html). This will score the similarity between your matlab labels and your k-means labels.

Alternatively you can create a [confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix) to visualise the mapping between your two labelsets.

Answer (score 1):

[I would use squared error](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat508/book/export/html/648#:%7E:text=The%20Objective%20Function%20in%20K,the%20pooled%20within%20covariance%20matrix.)

You are trying to minimize the total squared distance between each point and the mean coordinate of it's cluster.

Comment: Yes. This is the objective of centroid-based k-means. However, I need to evaluate the accuracy of the algorithm when it is used to cluster the dataset generated by matlab. The dataset generated in the form of clustered points where I have the cluster number of each point.